# CPU Scheduling and process completion

Tags: operating-system, cpu

In cpu scheduling after serving the burst time of a process we say that this process is over, then how does the applications keep running all the time ?

Answer (score 1):

> we say that this process is over

It's not *over*, it just isn't running (for a little while).

> how does the applications keep running all the time ?

Basically, it doesn't. The operating is constantly juggling many more processes than there are CPU cores. It does this by giving each process short amounts of time to run and then preserving their state until it's their turn again.

The operating system does this quickly and often enough that it looks that all the processes are running all the time.

Comment: I want a little more insight. Suppose a media player application is running.Sevral proceses will be running to serve this  application. Let one of the processes be to read data from hard disk. As you said this process will never end, CPU just tries to run it for a while.How does the CPU determines the time for running a while (Burst time). As literature says the burst time is initialized by some random value, we track the history of its run time, slowly it converges to actual burst time. But if the process itself is never ending how we will track the history ?

Comment: @preetam ......no.  You need to read up more on this subject.  The questions you are asking are not founded upon a sufficient depth of  understanding for an SO answer.  A thread that issues an I/O request for a disk read will have CPU execution removed from it until the I/O it requested has completed.  I cannot see how the SO Q&A format can help you:(